# How to find as string for Boolean type field in mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a field name and criteria to search for collection.

But the types of fields are various like `String`, `Number`, `Boolean`.

I tried like below;

```
const fieldName1 = 'active', fieldName2 = 'name'; // String type field
const criteria1 = 'true', criteria2 = 'Jack';  // Boolean type field
...

const find = async (fieldName, criteria) => await Users.find({[fieldName]: criteria};
```

Above `find` funtion is not working for `Boolean` type field.

How to find as `String` for `Boolean` type field in `mongoDB`?

Answer (score 0):

Try `criteria = true`, without the single quotes.

Comment: Maybe. But I don't know the type of field. It can be various.

Comment: Then this comes to mind: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#document-querying-by-multiple-data-types

Comment: So, I am not sure if it is possible... Could you please update your answer for my question?